# Detect when SKNode is added as child

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a Polygon class that is used as data container, but for debugging purposes I want to draw polygons by adding them as children to an SKNode. When I do this I want the Polygon object to add border sprite children to itself. Because of performance reasons I only want to add those sprites when the Polygon has been added as child to another node.

Is there any way that the Polygon object itself can detect that it has been added to the scene, or do I need to tell it by making an extra `createSprites` call after it has been added to the scene?

I guess I can poll the parent attribute, but I'm looking for something event driven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, you can define **property observers** for the properties of the class yours inherits from.

You could observe changes in the `parent` property of your custom SKNode subclass, like this:

```
class MyNode : SKNode {

    override var parent: SKNode? {
        didSet {
             // parent node changed; do something
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Like I mentioned in the comments, in Objective-C (where you can not use property observers) you can instead use Key-Value Observing (KVO), and observe changes in `SKNode`'s `parent` property:

Actual code:

```
- (instancetype) init
{
    if (self = [super init]){
        // REGISTER for KVO
        [self addObserver:self 
               forKeyPath:@"parent" 
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:NULL];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc 
{
    // UNREGISTER from KVO
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parent" context:NULL];
}

// Method that is called when any keyPath you subscribed to is modified
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
    // (Check keypath in case you are observing several different
    //  properties. Otherwise, remove if statement:)

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"parent"]) {

        // parent node changed; do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit vague. My question concerns objective-c. And I don't think that I want to extend those base classes. I was looking for something built in. But maybe there is no such solution.

Comment: Then, use Key-Value Observing and get notified when the property 'parent' changes value.

Comment: Fantastic compile error in Xcode 12.5.1: `Cannot observe read-only property 'parent'; it can't change`. You see? Parent node can't change. Wow!

Comment: This is actually fair only for the first part of the answer, KVO works well.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you could do it like this:

```
[node addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parent" options:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey context:nil];
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    //logic here
}
```

Or in this case simply subclass `SKNode` and override `setParent:`